# How to get values from hash if I know keys of another hash

Tags: ruby

I stucked on a trouble when I have instance method and a hash and I want to use attributes of method to iterate over that hash to retrieve value.
For example I have method:

```
class M
  def initialize(time, line)
    @time = YAML.load_file(time)
    @line = YAML.load_file(line)
  end

  def sum(from_station:, to_station:)
    array = @time['timing'] 
    lines = @line['lines']          
    line = @line['stations'] 
    from_station_line = line[from_station.to_s]
    to_station_line = line[to_station.to_s]
    str = from_station
    stop = to_station
    result = []
    result2 = []
    result3 = []
    time = 0
    if from_station_line[0] == to_station_line[0]
      loop do
      tmp = array.find{|x| x['start'] == str}
      break unless tmp
      result << tmp
      str = tmp['end']
      time = result.sum{|b| b['time']}
      break if str == stop
      end
      puts time
    else
      case array
    end
    p time, result2
   end
  end
end

a = M.new("./config/time.yml", "./config/config.yml")
a.sum(from_station: :tokyo, to_station: :milan)
```

and config.yml stations:

```
lines:
  - :black
  - :red
  - :yellow
stations:
  tokyo:
    - :black
  chicago:
    - :black
  amster:
    - :black
    - :red
  prague:
    - :black
  milan:
    - :black
    - :red
  bayern:
    - :black
    - :yellow
```

And here is time.yml

```
 timing:
  -
    start: :tokyo
    end: :chicago
    time: 6
    price: 3
  -
    start: :chicago
    end: :amster
    time: 4
    price: 2
  -
    start: :amster
    end: :prague
    time: 3.5
    price: 3
  -
    start: :bayern
    end: :milan
    time: 3.5
    price: 3
  -
    start: :milan
    end: :roma
    time: 3.5
    price: 3
  -
```

And I need to select if `from_station:` and `to_station:` on the same branch (black or red or both). Could i make it?
Another words: if user choose to move from station ":tokyo" to station ":milan" I need to know if these two stations on one line (:black, red or yellow). So to know that I need to manage config.yml file and iterate if line of ":tokyo" [black] == line of ":milan [yellow]

Comment: _"[...] to retrieve value"_ – what value? What is `sum` supposed to return? And what are the values for `from_station` and `to_station` when calling `sum`? Give some examples and explain the logic for retrieving the result. Furthermore, what are the _"keys from another hash"_ you are referring to in the question's title?

Comment: To retrieve value of hash (:black, red or yellow) branch. I edited it in my post

Comment: Now your example contains two methods: `sum` and `calculate_time`. I guess this is a typo? However, what is `a.calculate_time(from_station: :tokyo, to_station: :milan)` supposed to return? (and why)

Comment: Where does the `hash stations` come into play? What does it has to do with the rest of the code? The domain and problem is quite confusing given your example. We can guess the semantics (you want to calculate how long some trains need from A to B), but I do not understand where the data comes from or where the actual problem is. In the `sum` function you can access a value of the hash `@line` like e.g. this: `@line[to_station]`. Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: Could you provide desired result? Just examples of data you want to get from the each method.

Comment: @Stefan I edited my post, yes, it was typo

Comment: @Felix I just edited my post

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually in Ruby you won't use `loop` and `break` statements. The [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html) module will do most of that stuff for you. It might take a bit to get used to it, but then it will become naturally and allow you to quickly to lots of stuff. Note that other programming languages employ similar concepts.

In

```
  a = line.select {|k,v| k.to_sym == from_station}  #how to implement this condition?
  b = line.select {|k,v| k.to_sym == to_station}#
```

you do typical lookups in a Hash, which can be done by

```
def sum(from_station, to_station)
  from_station_colors = @lines[from_station]
  to_station_colors   = @lines[to_station]

  if (from_station_colors.nil? || from_station_colors.empty?)
    # from_station not found
  end
  # ...
end
```

The lookup in `timing` is a bit more complicated:

```rb
require 'yaml'

timings = YAML::load_file('timing.yml')['timing']

from_station = :tokyo
to_station = :chicago

# "t" (a timing entry) might be nil, thus the first select
# Note that there are other handy functions to make this more readable
# (left as an exercise)
transit = timings.select{|t| t}.select do |timing|
  # if the following line evaluates to "true", select this entry
  timing['start'] == from_station && timing['end'] == to_station
end

puts transit # {"start"=>:tokyo, "end"=>:chicago, "time"=>6, "price"=>3}
```

Your other question (find out if the locations share the same 'color') should probably be asked separately. Somehow, this task sounds like a homework assignment.

And welcome at StackOverflow! Please consider to be a as precise as possible with your next question(s) - while reducing the examples to a "good" minimum.

Comment: from_station_colors = @line[from_station] - returns nil

Comment: It's ok, I converted attribute of instance to string and it works. Thank you very much for complete answer!

Comment: But also want to say that here is wrong condition: transit = timings.select{|t| t}.select do |timing|